# Step size out range in Android Studio (Sliderbar)

Tags: android, kotlin, slider

I'm trying to give a step size in a sliderbar, and I get an

> IllegalStateException error: "The stepSize(200.0) must be 0, or a factor of the valueFrom(100.0)-valueTo(800.0) range".

I'm giving a step size of 200 in a range of 100 to 800.
I have to solve the problem using these values. If a solution with sliderbar is not possible, what else could I use?

I tried using seekbar but it won't let me setp in seekbar

Comment: As the error message intends: Did you try a step size of e.g. 100? Please explain why you "have to solve the problem using these values"? What is the purpose of a step size that, starting with `valueFrom`, doesn't hit the `valueTo`? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I can't know exactly what you're doing without a piece of code, but this site gives info on every method related to sliders.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider#setStepSize(float)

Specifically, here is what it says about setting the step size.

> setStepSize
>
> public void setStepSize (float stepSize)
>
> Sets the step size to use to mark the ticks.
>
> Setting this value to 0 will make the slider operate in continuous
> mode. Setting this value to a number greater than 0 will make the
> slider operate in discrete mode.
>
> The step size must evenly divide the range described by the valueFrom and valueTo, it must be a factor of the range. If the step size is not a factor of the range, an IllegalStateException will be thrown when this view is laid out.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your step size to 100. May be it will help you.